# Need help converting this code snippet from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

```
select pln_products as "Products",round((sum(PLN_ANNUAL)/12),2) AS "Monthly Charges",count(pln_products) as "Count"
from test1
where pln_start_date<=(SELECT LAST_DAY(:select_date) FROM dual)
and ((pln_end_date is null) or (pln_end_date >= (SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(:select_date,-1))+1) from dual)))
and PLN_CUSTOMER_NAME= :PLN_CUSTOMER_NAME
group by pln_products;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, why did that not work?

Comment: I have written this in Oracle, need to convert this so that it runs in SQL Server

Comment: Which part do you need help with? i.e. what specifically is preventing your conversion from working on SQL Server?

Comment: When the code is being executed its throwing exception as :
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ':'-
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ':'-

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use variables. in T-SQL you need to declare a variable first and they are prefixed with an @ rather than a :

Comment: Maybe. I don't know SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

you do not use the double apostroph " in SQL. You use the single apostroph ' .

You also have to declare the Variables first, so you can use them later in your Query.

The date - functions, that I used look a little complicated, but they work.

```
declare @PLN_CUSTOMER_NAME nvarchar(150) = ...  -- define the Variables
declare @select_date date = ...

select pln_products as 'Products'
    ,round((sum(PLN_ANNUAL)/12),2) AS 'Monthly Charges'
    ,count(pln_products) as 'Count'
from test1
where pln_start_date <= (SELECT dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(@select_date),month(getdate()),1))) FROM dual)
    and ((pln_end_date is null) or (pln_end_date >= (SELECT dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 2, datefromparts(year(@select_date),month(getdate()), 1))) from dual)))
    and PLN_CUSTOMER_NAME= @PLN_CUSTOMER_NAME
group by pln_products
```

Hope i could help you... Max